# How to use twitter bootstrap 3.1.1 modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've seen a lot of examples of modals. But they work perfectly only with bootstrap 2 ( css files)
When I use it with bootstrap 3.1.1 css files . It doesn't works.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>
    <div id="example" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">
         <div class="modal-header">
             <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
             <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
             <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
             <p>You can add some text here.</p>             
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>
             <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
         </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#example" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch demo modal</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Go to bootstrap documentation under the modal section, include the bootstrap js & css then paste source code from the documentation. Modal is working fine in 3.x.x version.

Comment: Already downloaded latest css,js files. It doesn't works..

Comment: Doesnt work is mean modal didnt show up?

Comment: See the @JoshC answer with example below for all bootstrap version.

Comment: http://sunrisetemplate.besaba.com Check it on my web site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Bootstrap 3 documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), you need to structure your HTML like this:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jN2yU/)

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
             <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
             <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
             <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
             <p>You can add some text here.</p>             
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>
             <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you got what point you have missing for trigger the modal on clicked?

Comment: Sorry could you help me? I have a new problem. Backdrop over modal. I can't click nowhere

Comment: @Dj.Sunrise If it's something small, I can answer it quickly, otherwise you will need to open up another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @Dj.Sunrise Give `.modal` a higher `z-index` value.. `.modal { z-index:9999 }` should work..

Answer (score 2):

You have missing and invalid CSS classes. Main problem is `hide fade in`.

Here is the [js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Jcp9G/).

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>
    <div id="example" class="modal fade" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"> 
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                 <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
                <p>You can add some text here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"> 
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p> <a data-toggle="modal" href="#example" 
     class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch demo modal</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: The use of the ID element was useful, this way I can have multiple modals on one page.